# PHP If Else statement not working correctly

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a php if else statement which checks if the query contains a string. if it doesn't it will output a style-sheet. If it contains a string it will get the users style-sheet. However it seems to only be outputting the 1st fixed style-sheet apposed to the users set one.

```html
<?php $user_data_load = $con->query("SELECT theme
FROM users
WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['user']['id']."'");?>
<?php 
if (!isset($user_data_load) or !is_array($user_data_load) or empty($user_data_load)): ?>
<link id="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme_default.css" type='text/css'>
<?php else: ?>
<?php while($userloaded = $user_data_load->fetch_object()): ?>
<link id='stylesheet' rel='stylesheet' href='<?= $userloaded->theme?>' type='text/css'>
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Pleeease! Separate logic from HTML and use PDO. Your query is at high risk!

Comment: Your if can only evaluate to true because `$user_data_load` is never a array.

Comment: query will always return a mysqli_result object, if the query succeeds. But succeeding doesn't meen it has rows to return. So ask for numrows!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some notes to your if:

```
if (!isset($user_data_load) or !is_array($user_data_load) or empty($user_data_load)): ?>
```

`!isset($user_data_load)` will **always** be false. `isset` checks if a variable is set, and since you set it yourself, it will always return true, it doesn't matter whats *in* that variable.

`!is_array($user_data_load)` will **always** be true, because `$con->query` *never* returns a array, therefore you'll always use the default stylesheet.

Try it like this:

```
<?php

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT theme
        FROM users
        WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['user']['id']);
$stmt->execute();

if ($data = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_object()) {
    echo '<link id="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" href="' . $data->theme . '" type="text/css">';
} else {
    echo '<link id="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme_default.css" type="text/css">';
}
```

Comment: I tried the code you posted, however it doesn't seem to work, no errors either :/

Comment: Could you help me please

Comment: I don't know how if I don't know what the problem is. Enable error-output, var_dump the variables, see where it starts to fail.

Comment: ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bindParam() in /storage/www/socialnetwk.com/home.php on line 67

Comment: Yes, it does. Edited my answer

Answer (score -1):

Every id will be 'stylesheet'. Take out the id to prevent rebinding.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='<?= $userloaded->theme?>' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: The ID is used for a JS script to allow the user to change different style sheets live

Comment: Okay, Check your query results then.

Comment: My query results return fine with the theme